# is there a testing tool for Linux shell such as Selenium for the web?

Tags: linux, shell, testing, automation

I look for a tool in Linux for to make the test in easy form as selenium.

Because you can get a record file of any session with Selenium Firefox extension, and the method is only press the record button in the extension and make the actions in the web.

I tried with Cucumber, but the job mates (from support) hate to learn a new language for to make a testing cases...they prefer a boring spreadsheet to fill manually...

And I have to confess something, it's embarrassing...I thought or imagined that ttyrec "the magical tool" can record the shell session and later I can replay the actions with the record file...but it is like as "ascii film"...I feel a bit silly...sorry.

Then, I look for a tool more or less to "ttyrec" but it is as "selenium for  to shell".

Comment: You want something that can record and play back commands? Or you want something that can do that as well as capture the output and compare future runs against the captured output?

Answer (score 3):

its scripting language is a little clunky, but I think [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) can do what you're looking for. You can use [autoexpect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/autoexpect) to "record" a test and generate the file for expect to rerun the test later

Comment: I'm not sure expect can do the capturing part of things really but the replay checking it definitely can.

Comment: @EtanReisner good point. I've amended my answer to include autoexpect for capturing

Comment: I always forget about autoexpect. I think that's probably more-or-less exactly the sort of tool the OP wants here.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But I have been testing autoexpect.

And it check all prompt by default and when it is a ssh connection show the last connection as date, then the script.exp tried to check this line.

But if you call "autoexpect -p", the autoexpect only check the last line...it is a few blind but it runs fine.